# Program type already present in android support

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to run the application this error occurs:

> **Error:Program type already present:android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver**

I think that it is a dependency issue but I do not know how to solve this.

**App level gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.faisal.mychat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
 }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
}

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project level gradle:**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
   }
}
    allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
 }

task clean
    (type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is it, but I notice that a buildToolsVersion isn't specified. Couldn't hurt to add it. Say  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" after compileSdkVersion

Answer (score 0):

**At first add**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

Do not add dependency with `+` . Please try to use the same and specific version of the dependency for all.

**For example
Instead of**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
```

**use**

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`